# How to display user friendly error messages from python - SQlAlchemy SQL server to display in the front end

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I am using `Flask` and `SQLAlchemy` - `SQL Server`.

I am getting the `error` message below:-

```
(pyodbc.IntegrityError) ('23000', \"[23000] [Microsoft] [ODBC SQL
Server Driver][SQL Server]Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 
'UQ__Model__67DC63B54CA06362'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
'dbo.Models'. The duplicate key value is (model111111111t). (2627)
(SQLExecDirectW); [23000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL 
Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)\")\n[SQL: INSERT IN
TO [Models] ([ModelName], [Description], [DateCreated]) OUTPUT
inserted.[ModelID] VALUES (?, ?, ?)]\n[parameters: ('model111111111t',
'test  description', datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 20, 20, 36, 9, 
290718))]\n(Background on this error at:
http://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
```

But I just want to show simple error messages like  "`Name already exists" or "`Duplicate Name Error`" to display in the front end, instead of the whole SQL server message.

Here is the code I am testing:

```
try:                       
    new_model = WCOModels(ModelName=data['ModelName'], Description = data['Description']) 
    db.session.add(new_model)  
    db.session.commit()    
    return jsonify({'message': 'Model added successfully'})  

except Exception as e:
    app.logger.error("%s, Line no:  %s, %s() , %s", type(e).__name__, sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno, sys._getframe().f_code.co_name, str(e))
    return jsonify(str(e))
```

How do I extract that from the exception?

Comment: HI can you post relevant code snippets so as to provide more context? You could place the code that causes this error within a `try except` block. For more on Python exception handling read [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions)

Comment: try:
                        
            new_model = WCOModels(ModelName=data['ModelName'], Description = data['Description']) 
            db.session.add(new_model)  
            db.session.commit()    
            return jsonify({'message': 'Model added successfully'})  

        except Exception as e:
            app.logger.error("%s, Line no:  %s, %s() , %s", type(e).__name__, sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno, sys._getframe().f_code.co_name, str(e))
            return jsonify(str(e))

Comment: Hi can you edit your question add the code there instead of posting it as a comment? That way it would be readable.

Comment: point is i want to display , simple error message like  "Name already exists" or "Duplicate Name Error"  to the front end.  not the whole SQL server error message

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the log message with necessary information. Say you want to print just the type of the error.

```
try:
   new_model = WCOModels(ModelName=data['ModelName'], Description = data['Description'])
   db.session.add(new_model)
   db.session.commit()
   return jsonify({'message': 'Model added successfully'})
except Exception as e:
   app.logger.error(type(e).__name__)
   return jsonify(str(e))
```

Comment: there can be many exceptions . should i raise a seperate exception message for each of them ?

Comment: If you just want to print the type of the error you may add it in the logger like `type(e).__name__`